# Store Locator is not working.Getting GeoServiceWrapperException exception

Tags: geolocation, sap-commerce-cloud

store locator is not working.  I am getting null response for following line of code:

```
gps = getGeoWebServiceWrapper().geocodeAddress(generateGeoAddressForSearchQuery(currentBaseStore, address));**
```

Here **generateGeoAddressForSearchQuery()** is a method where i am setting country and city name,**geocodeAddress()** is a method of class **MockedGeoServiceWrapper.java** . In this method  i am getting GeoServiceWrapperException for following line of code.

```
final GPS gpsAddress = geoMap.get(StringUtils.lowerCase(address.getCity()));
```

**Error**:

> de.hybris.platform.storelocator.exception.GeoServiceWrapperException: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=scottsdale%2BUS&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyDq6glaTkn6dXSJ1OwAv75qkMAE1vGXqZw":Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connecti

Please find below complete error logs.

**Error Logs:**

> ERROR [hybrisHTTP21] [SetStoreFilter] [UserSessionId:89FD76C573C4A389D84083D24F967E37] Failed to get GeoLocaion.For input string: "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1"
>   ERROR [hybrisHTTP24] [SetStoreFilter] [UserSessionId:89FD76C573C4A389D84083D24F967E37] Failed to get GeoLocaion.For input string: "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1"
>   ERROR [hybrisHTTP5] [DefaultDTStoreFinderService] [UserSessionId:89FD76C573C4A389D84083D24F967E37] Failed to resolve location for [scottsdale]
>   de.hybris.platform.storelocator.exception.GeoServiceWrapperException: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=scottsdale%2BUS&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyDq6glaTkn6dXSJ1OwAv75qkMAE1vGXqZw":Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connecti
>           at de.hybris.platform.storelocator.impl.GoogleMapTools.geocodeAddress(GoogleMapTools.java:166)
>           at de.hybris.platform.storelocator.impl.GoogleMapsServiceWrapper.geocodeAddress(GoogleMapsServiceWrapper.java:59)
>           at com.discounttire.integration.services.storefinder.impl.DefaultDTStoreFinderService.getPointByAddress(DefaultDTStoreFinderService.java:297)
>           at com.discounttire.facades.storefinder.impl.DefaultDTStoreFinderFacade.getPointByAddress(DefaultDTStoreFinderFacade.java:76)
>           at com.discounttire.storefront.controllers.pages.StoreLocatorPageController.findStores(StoreLocatorPageController.java:216)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)

Comment: I can access your URL from my side. It's propably a network issue. Are you behind a firewall?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the number of requests you have sent to Google Geocoding Api ?
For free account Google have some limits (Daily, and per second).